# Specify a repeating number for unittest

Tags: python-3.x

I plan to test a bi_search function

```
def bi_search(L: List[int], find: int) -> int:
    if len(L) < 1: #terninating case 
        return None 
    else:
        mid = len(L) // 2
        logging.info(f"mid: {mid}")
        if find == L[mid]:
            return find 
        if find > L[mid]:
            upper_half = L[mid+1:]
            logging.info(f"upper_half: {upper_half}")
            return bi_search(upper_half, find)
        if find < L[mid]:
            lower_half = L[:mid-1]
            logging.info(f"lower_half: {lower_half}")
            return bi_search(lower_half, find)
```

And the TestCase

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bi_search(self):
        L = list(range(-100,101,3 ))
        find = random.randint(-100, 101)
        logging.info(f"find: {find}")
        result = bi_search(L, find)
        print(f"\nThe result is {result}.")

for i in range(30):
    unittest.main()
```

Employ a `for loop` to iterate the testing 30 times.

Unfortunately, it run once and stoped

```
In [58]: !python threeSum.py                                                                              
INFO find: -96
INFO mid: 33
INFO lower_half: [-100, -97, -94, -91, -88, -85, -82, -79, -76, -73, -70, -67, -64, -61, -58, -55, -52, -49, -46, -43, -40, -37, -34, -31, -28, -25, -22, -19, -16, -13, -10, -7]
INFO mid: 16
INFO lower_half: [-100, -97, -94, -91, -88, -85, -82, -79, -76, -73, -70, -67, -64, -61, -58]
INFO mid: 7
INFO lower_half: [-100, -97, -94, -91, -88, -85]
INFO mid: 3
INFO lower_half: [-100, -97]
INFO mid: 1
INFO upper_half: []

The result is None.
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

How could specify a running time for the TestCase so I can run as many times as intented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python run unittests continuously or each test multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148221/python-run-unittests-continuously-or-each-test-multiple-times)